# How to change search result display order in dropdown

Tags: jquery, mysql, sql, autocomplete

I have created jquery autocomplete search there when i search something drop down menu doesn list

Comment: `order by title DESC`

Comment: @SpYk3HH  : what i realy want is to first display the words which have the search query as starting of word (chocoalte), not in second word (fruit chocalte). please advice

Comment: What is your logic for sorting?  From what it looks like, you are trying to first sort by what index **cho** occurs in the string, then by alphabetical order?  If so, it looks like your correct order should be 1) chocolate, 2) milk chocolate, 3) fruit chocolate, 4) abc per chocolates

Comment: ORDER BY string LIKE '$searchr%' ? Ah, Ed's got the right idea

Comment: How big is your data set?

Comment: @Strawberry : arround 400 records

Comment: For a data set this small, I'd just grab the whole thing and do the ordering in the application-level code, so no more round trips to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd order by the position "cho" was found at first, then by the entire title as a tiebreaker. You can find the position using the [LOCATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_locate) function:

```
... ORDER BY LOCATE(searchstring, REPLACE(title, ' ', '')), title
```

Comment: do i have to put this for after ORDER BY on my query , Please advice

Comment: yes, in your query replace your current order by statement with this

Comment: You'd replace your existing `order by title ASC` with this. Note that where I say `searchstring`, I mean your `$searchr` variable. I didn't want to give a full example because you should be doing prepared statements with mysqli or PDO instead of interpolating the `$searchr` variable.

Comment: @EdGibbs : $query="SELECT DISTINCT title FROM content where REPLACE(title, ' ', '') like '%".$searchr."%'AND categories_id=83 ORDER BY LOCATE( '%".$searchr."%' , REPLACE(title, ' ', '')), title ";   this is what i put , but still the same resutls , kindly please advice

Comment: You need to take the `%` out of the `LOCATE` string: ...`ORDER BY LOCATE('".$searchr."', REPLACE(title, ' ', '')), title";`

Comment: @EdGibbs : thanks it works, Kindly please check update section of my question, i tried to use the LOCATE fucntion on another cenarion for UNION table query, where i want to use the LCOATE for category titles and contetn title s but for that its not working . please advice me

Comment: What does "not working" mean - syntax error? PHP error? No results? Wrong results? You can debug the query by running a plain version of it in MySQLAdmin or MySQL Workbench. One thing for sure: you can only `ORDER BY` after the last `UNION`.

Comment: @EdGibbs : i put the ORDER BY only for last UNION (which means near group by ) and run the code on phpmyadmin it gives error " #1054 - Unknown column 'a.title' in 'order clause'"